# Personalization on Layout Service not working when calling from JSS App

Tags: personalization, jss

My Sitecore CD website in IIS is http://cd.my-website.com with a role as ContentDelivery. This site contains Sitecore and custom API code in Headless mode.

The React code for the JSS app is on a different website http://fe.my-website.com (No Sitecore). JSS App is connecting to the http://cd.my-website.com through Layout ServiceHost.

All sites are separate in IIS and also separate folders pointing to the same database on a local machine.

The sites are working fine except personalization.
We have set some personalization based on custom rule and some OOB rules.

The personalization is not working when I access the site using the http://fe.my-website.com.

I checked very weird behavior for the below URL

[http://cd.my-website.com/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2Fenterprise&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey={ourAPIKey}](http://cd.my-website.com/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=%2Fenterprise&sc_lang=en&sc_apikey=%7BourAPIKey%7D)

When it is accessed through the FE website, the Layout service is called as an Ajax request and it can be found in XHR under network in the developer toolbar. The site is not showing any personalization when called in this way. Even I set some very basic OOB Sitecore personalization like date or day or month.

In XHR, I can find the call to the layout service. When I checked the response, I didn't find any personalized content. When I opened the same URL in the browser (right-click and open in new tab), I can see all personalization applied correctly. The output is different than the Ajax request.

When I deployed the React code in Sitecore site under /dist/myproject/ and tried to access personalization worked fine (Integrated mode).

Edit 1:

Sitecore 9.1 initial release

License: xDB enabled

xDB settings: Default/No Change

Comment: Can you check if IIS sets any kind of caching settings on the Node.js app

Comment: Also make sure you are including cookie information when you call the cd LayoutService from your front-end site. The fetch() function doesn't do this by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the issue lies in the passing of the personalization context during Ajax requests from the JSS app to the Layout Service. To address this, it's important to thoroughly examine how your React app is making calls to the layout service and vice versa.

Check the implementation in your React app to ensure that any relevant user or session information required for personalization is being properly included in the Ajax requests. Additionally, review the configuration and handling of personalization context within the Layout Service to ensure it correctly interprets and applies the received information.